# Rename existing shortcut with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, shortcut-file

I need to change the name of desktop application shortcut when I publish the next release of the application. I am updating my Inno Setup configuration file and I generated a new shortcut with the new name but the old shortcut is not updated or deleted.

Can I use some task or function to do it?

This my current configuration for shortcut icon.

```
[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; \
    GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

...

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; \
    Tasks: desktopicon
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`[InstallDelete]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=installdeletesection) entry to delete the unwanted/old shortcut/file:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\New Shortcut"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; \
    Tasks: desktopicon

[InstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "{commondesktop}\Old Shortcut.lnk"
```